# Morse code translator in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, homework, morse-code

I'm writing a Morse code translator for homework in C#. It takes an input from the user and returns the Morse code version of their input. I understand that this code may look horrible, so how could I improve it in terms of efficiency and readability?

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MorseCodeTranslator
{
    class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<char, string> translator;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitialiseDictionary();
            getUserInput();
        }

        private static void InitialiseDictionary()
        {
            char dot = '.';
            char dash = '−';

            translator = new Dictionary<char, string>()
            {
                {'a', string.Concat(dot, dash)},
                {'b', string.Concat(dash, dot, dot, dot)},
                {'c', string.Concat(dash, dot, dash, dot)},
                {'d', string.Concat(dash, dot, dot)},
                {'e', dot.ToString()},
                {'f', string.Concat(dot, dot, dash, dot)},
                {'g', string.Concat(dash, dash, dot)},
                {'h', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot, dot)},
                {'i', string.Concat(dot, dot)},
                {'j', string.Concat(dot, dash, dash, dash)},
                {'k', string.Concat(dash, dot, dash)},
                {'l', string.Concat(dot, dash, dot, dot)},
                {'m', string.Concat(dash, dash)},
                {'n', string.Concat(dash, dot)},
                {'o', string.Concat(dash, dash, dash)},
                {'p', string.Concat(dot, dash, dash, dot)},
                {'q', string.Concat(dash, dash, dot, dash)},
                {'r', string.Concat(dot, dash, dot)},
                {'s', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot)},
                {'t', string.Concat(dash)},
                {'u', string.Concat(dot, dot, dash)},
                {'v', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot, dash)},
                {'w', string.Concat(dot, dash, dash)},
                {'x', string.Concat(dash, dot, dot, dash)},
                {'y', string.Concat(dash, dot, dash, dash)},
                {'z', string.Concat(dash, dash, dot, dot)},
                {'0', string.Concat(dash, dash, dash, dash, dash)},
                {'1', string.Concat(dot, dash, dash, dash, dash)},  
                {'2', string.Concat(dot, dot, dash, dash, dash)},
                {'3', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot, dash, dash)},
                {'4', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot, dot, dash)},
                {'5', string.Concat(dot, dot, dot, dot, dot)},
                {'6', string.Concat(dash, dot, dot, dot, dot)},
                {'7', string.Concat(dash, dash, dot, dot, dot)},
                {'8', string.Concat(dash, dash, dash, dot, dot)},
                {'9', string.Concat(dash, dash, dash, dash, dot)}
            };
        }

        public static void getUserInput()
        {
            string input;
            Console.WriteLine("What did you want to say?");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            input = input.ToLower();
            Console.WriteLine("Your output is: " + translate(input));
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string translate(string input)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach(char character in input)
            {
                if(translator.ContainsKey(character))
                {
                    sb.Append(translator[character] + " ");
                } else if (character == ' ')
                {
                    sb.Append("/ ");
                } else 
                {
                    sb.Append(character + " ");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit weird to see the symbols called 'dot' and 'dash' when they normally are pronounced 'di' and 'dah', but that's language rather than code.

Comment: Take a look at the `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` method. In `translate()` the string concatenation is not complex but in the long run string formatters are cleaner, easier to read, and less error prone than `+` operation concatenation.

Comment: `translate()` would be more robust if it accepted capital letters by `ToLower`ing them before dictionary lookup,

Comment: Why is `'  '` not in the dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is `translator` really a translator? IMO a better name could be `dictionary`.

I also don't understand an idea to create variables like `dot` and `dash`.
`{'a', ".-"}` would be much clearer.

Don't use misleading function names. The function `getUserInput` does much more than getting something from user! It also translates the text and prints it. So, in `Main`, I'd write:

```
input = getUserInput();
morse = translate(input);
PrintOnScreen(morse);
```

Be consistent in naming: now some functions have names starting with capital letter, some not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now making the changes. Is there a better data structure to use instead of a dictionary? I'm not familiar with all the different storage methods with C#.

Comment: I  think Piotr is hinting at the NAME of your variable, I think a proper compromise would be translatorDictionary.

Comment: `dictionary` is a lousy name. It IS a dictionary. How about something with the word `encoder` in it?

Comment: Using a variable for the `dot` and `dash` is actually a *good* thing, as this can allow easier modification of the programme to be configured by the user in the future. (I may want to use different characters for them.)

Answer (score 4):

The answers are perfect. But I want to improve. I changed your code little bit.
In any case a developper wants to use it; Here is what I did:

- Change dictionary
- Specifiy private/public access modifiers
- Take press enter to exit code outside of the "GetUserInput"
- Change dictionary name as _morseAlphabetDictionary
- Removing dash/dot local values.
- Change initialise as initialize
- Get user input now detects "empty inputs"

```
public class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<char, string> _morseAlphabetDictionary;

    static void Main()
    {
        InitializeDictionary();

        Console.WriteLine("What did you want to say?");
        string userInput = GetUserInput();
        Console.WriteLine("Morse alphabet output is: " + Translate(userInput));

        Console.WriteLine("[Press ANY KEY to exit]");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void InitializeDictionary()
    {
        _morseAlphabetDictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>()
                                   {
                                       {'a', ".-"},
                                       {'b', "-..."},
                                       {'c', "-.-."},
                                       {'d', "-.."},
                                       {'e', "."},
                                       {'f', "..-."},
                                       {'g', "--."},
                                       {'h', "...."},
                                       {'i', ".."},
                                       {'j', ".---"},
                                       {'k', "-.-"},
                                       {'l', ".-.."},
                                       {'m', "--"},
                                       {'n', "-."},
                                       {'o', "---"},
                                       {'p', ".--."},
                                       {'q', "--.-"},
                                       {'r', ".-."},
                                       {'s', "..."},
                                       {'t', "-"},
                                       {'u', "..-"},
                                       {'v', "...-"},
                                       {'w', ".--"},
                                       {'x', "-..-"},
                                       {'y', "-.--"},
                                       {'z', "--.."},
                                       {'0', "-----"},
                                       {'1', ".----"},
                                       {'2', "..---"},
                                       {'3', "...--"},
                                       {'4', "....-"},
                                       {'5', "....."},
                                       {'6', "-...."},
                                       {'7', "--..."},
                                       {'8', "---.."},
                                       {'9', "----."}
                                   };
    }

    private static string GetUserInput()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            input = input.ToLower();
        }

        return input;
    }

    private static string Translate(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char character in input)
        {
            if (_morseAlphabetDictionary.ContainsKey(character))
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(_morseAlphabetDictionary[character] + " ");
            }
            else if (character == ' ')
            {
                stringBuilder.Append("/ ");
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(character + " ");
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, looks pretty similar to my code after the edits now. :)

Comment: I'd rather turn `InitializeDictionary` into a side-effect free function and use it as initializer for `_morseAlphabetDictionary`. Or just drop the function entirely, it doesn't really add anything.

Answer (score 2):

- Everything above is good input
- The code I have does this in a WinForms application, but the principle of converting text to morse is the same.
- You can do it many ways. I am showing a dictionary and a switch statement approach.
- The dictionary is a good approach and gives good flexibility as others stated
- The dot dash terminology is arbitrary and is fine. As stated above, it gives flexibility to use anything in place of it, ex: "AB ABB ABAB" etc.
- The approach I took splits the message into separate strings everywhere there is a space and treats that as a word

  - (assuming there is a single space between each word in the message you want to convert).
- Then you can iterate through each word and perform any word-specific operations you want.
- When you are converting each word, you iterate through each character and you convert it to the morse equivalent and then append it to your "morse" string.
- A stringbuilder would also work instead of `morseCode += "something"`
- When you do `morseCode += GetMorseForChar(character)` you can use `GetMorseForChar()` **or** `_morseAlphabetDictionary[character]`.
- The latter gives you the "morse" value for the `character` key.

  ```
  static string Dot = "∙ ";
  static string Dash = "- ";
  private static Dictionary<char, string> _morseAlphabetDictionary = CreateMorseAlphabetDictionary();

  private static Dictionary<char, string> CreateMorseAlphabetDictionary()
  {
      return new Dictionary<char, string>()
      {
              { 'A', Dot + Dash },
              { 'B', Dash + Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { 'C', Dash + Dot + Dash + Dot },
              { 'D', Dash + Dot + Dot },
              { 'E', Dot },
              { 'F', Dot + Dot + Dash + Dot },
              { 'G', Dash + Dash + Dot },
              { 'H', Dot + Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { 'I', Dot + Dot },
              { 'J', Dot + Dash + Dash + Dash },
              { 'K', Dash + Dot + Dash },
              { 'L', Dot + Dash + Dot + Dot },
              { 'M', Dash + Dash },
              { 'N', Dash + Dot },
              { 'O', Dash + Dash + Dash },
              { 'P', Dot + Dash + Dash + Dot },
              { 'Q', Dash + Dash + Dot + Dash },
              { 'R', Dot + Dash + Dot },
              { 'S', Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { 'T', Dash },
              { 'U', Dot + Dot + Dash },
              { 'V', Dot + Dot + Dot + Dash },
              { 'W', Dot + Dash + Dash },
              { 'X', Dash + Dot + Dot + Dash },
              { 'Y', Dash + Dot + Dash + Dash },
              { 'Z', Dash + Dash + Dot + Dot },
              { ' ', "\n" },
              { '_', "\n" },
              { '0', Dash + Dash + Dash + Dash + Dash },
              { '1', Dot + Dash + Dash + Dash + Dash },
              { '2', Dot + Dot + Dash + Dash + Dash },
              { '3', Dot + Dot + Dot + Dash + Dash },
              { '4', Dot + Dot + Dot + Dot + Dash },
              { '5', Dot + Dot + Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { '6', Dash + Dot + Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { '7', Dash + Dash + Dot + Dot + Dot },
              { '8', Dash + Dash + Dash + Dot + Dot },
              { '9', Dash + Dash + Dash + Dash + Dot }
           };
        }

        private void calculateMorseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string[] words = englishTxtBox.Text.ToUpper().Split(' ');
           string morseCode = ConvertWordsToMorse(words);

           MessageBox.Show(morseCode);
        }

        private string ConvertWordsToMorse(string[] words)
        {
           string morseCode = string.Empty;
           foreach (string word in words)
           {
              char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
              morseCode += ConvertLettersToMorse(chars) + "\n";//$"{"",7}";
           }
           return morseCode;
        }

        private string ConvertLettersToMorse(char[] chars)
        {
           string morseCode = string.Empty;
           foreach (char character in chars)
           {
              morseCode += GetMorseForChar(character) + $"{"",3}";
           }
           return morseCode;
        }

        private string GetMorseForCharFromDictionary(char character)
        {
           return _morseAlphabetDictionary[character];
        }

        private string GetMorseForChar(char character)
        {
           string dot = "∙ ";
           string dash = "- ";

           switch (character)
           {
              case 'A': return dot + dash;

              case 'B': return dash + dot + dot + dot;

              case 'C': return dash + dot + dash + dot;

              case 'D': return dash + dot + dot;

              case 'E': return dot;

              case 'F': return dot + dot + dash + dot;

              case 'G': return dash + dash + dot;

              case 'H': return dot + dot + dot + dot;

              case 'I': return dot + dot;

              case 'J': return dot + dash + dash + dash;

              case 'K': return dash + dot + dash;

              case 'L': return dot + dash + dot + dot;

              case 'M': return dash + dash;

              case 'N': return dash + dot;

              case 'O': return dash + dash + dash;

              case 'P': return dot + dash + dash + dot;

              case 'Q': return dash + dash + dot + dash;

              case 'R': return dot + dash + dot;

              case 'S': return dot + dot + dot;

              case 'T': return dash;

              case 'U': return dot + dot + dash;

              case 'V': return dot + dot + dot + dash;

              case 'W': return dot + dash + dash;

              case 'X': return dash + dot + dot + dash;

              case 'Y': return dash + dot + dash + dash;

              case 'Z': return dash + dash + dot + dot;

              case ' ': return "\n";

              case '_': goto case ' ';

              case '0': return dash + dash + dash + dash + dash;

              case '1': return dot + dash + dash + dash + dash;

              case '2': return dot + dot + dash + dash + dash;

              case '3': return dot + dot + dot + dash + dash;

              case '4': return dot + dot + dot + dot + dash;

              case '5': return dot + dot + dot + dot + dot;

              case '6': return dash + dot + dot + dot + dot;

              case '7': return dash + dash + dot + dot + dot;

              case '8': return dash + dash + dash + dot + dot;

              case '9': return dash + dash + dash + dash + dot;

              default: return "";
           }
        }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

using a dictionary is a great way to organize the language and even keep it open for extension.

Naming conventions are really important and not following the 'norm' for a language can be sacrilege to some programmers and for good reason. It allows programmers to understand at a glance the scope and purpose of the variable, function, class, etcetera.

C# has some common naming conventions, namely (this is not holy writ):

- Pascal Case for method names, properties, classes: ie `MyBigClass`
- Underscore plus camel case for private variables: ie
  `_thisIsMyVariable`

also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx